# Where should I put navigation code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to skip the login page if there is a token in local storage, but I don't want to move the logic to `App`, because I want `LoginPage` to remain my base page.
Currently, I have this code and it works.

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var localStorage = new LocalStorage();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localStorage.Get("key")))
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainTabbedPage(true));
    }

    base.OnAppearing();

    // some unrelated code...
}
```

The problem with it is that sometimes (quite often), the login page is visible for a fraction of a second, until it navigates to the `MainTabbedPage`. Can I put the navigation code from `OnAppearing` to page constructor? If yes, should I put it before or after `InitializeComponent();`? Note, that some time in the application, I might call `PopToRootAsync()` in order to return to the login page, which this time, I might want to display.

Also, please tell me if something is wrong with this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer was correct and helped you solve the problem please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend creating a splash screen. That way you can have a minimum time before the next screen shows and perform tasks. While the splash screen is visible, check if the user token is valid and then proceed to displaying the login screen or whatever screen you want to display. 
Please tell me if you need further help.

Comment: sounds like a great idea, however, I would also like to know the answer to my question. if nothing else, I'll stick with Your solution.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by "the question." I thought I had answered it, but if not please just comment what you would like me to answer. :)

Comment: Can I put the navigation code from `OnAppearing` to page constructor? If yes, should I put it before or after `InitializeComponent();`? Note, that some time in the application, I might call `PopToRootAsync()` in order to return to the login page, which this time, I might want to display.

Comment: Also, as I said, it's necessary that the root page be the login page.

Comment: If the code runs fairly quick, I would put it in the constructor since the screen will turn white until it is done (should be quick) and then if the activity is changed via Intent (token valid) then the login screen will never show. I recommend trying this.